# understanding break statement and handling it for existing code

Tags: c++, for-loop, break

In the below example, i have problem in handling the break statement. For country = US, somearray will be of length one only. but in case of "DE", length is more than one. but given program, since break statement is used to get out after processing 1st row, it will not suite for DE country since DE country has more than one rows Since re-
using is a better way, checking if there is someway i can re use the same logic for country =DE as well

```
        if(country == "US" || country == "DE")
        {

            for(int i = 0; i < somearray.length(); i++)
            {

                if( (payment == "USD") )
                {
                    if(amount > 0)
                    {
                        //do something  
                    }

                    if( balance.is_positive())
                    {
                        // do something
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Note : this is not actual code.. just wrote like an example to understand..

Comment: why notjust remove the `break`?

Comment: what is payment related to? is it only for US country? cos as far as i see, your break depends on payment and not somearray

Comment: @Codeek, Oops, missed that, thank you

Comment: `=` is assignment. You either meant `==` or `strcmp`

Comment: I concur with Alf. If what you say is true, the `break`  no sense in the first place. You already said "For country = US, `somearray` will be of length one only". I.e. after the iteration you'll break *anyway* because the condition of the for-loop will fail and thusly break all on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if(country = "US" || country = "DE")
        {

            for(int i = 0; i < somearray.length(); i++)
            {

                if( (payment == "USD") )
                {
                    if(amount > 0)
                    {
                        //do something  
                    }

                    if( balance.is_positive())
                    {
                        // do something
                    }
                  if(somearray.length()==1)  // as per Your requirement country **us** has **length 1** ,in this can break the loop 
                    {break;}
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood, You want to process each element in `somearray`, Therefore removing break statement will suffice. `if (payment = "USD")` is useless here, a simple statement `payment="USD"` would suffice. Moreover since that is an assignment which is same for all the loop iterations, pull it outside and assign before the loop.